# Unable to insert value in the newly column added in the wp-user

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a new column in wp-user named as twitter_username and its datatype is varchar. 
In sign up form I have also added a new field named
   as twitter username. 
when I signup, I am unable to save that
   field's value in "twitter_username" column in wp-user table. i have
   tried following code all values are storing in the wp-user table
   instead of the "twitter_username".

```
$new_customer_data = apply_filters('woocommerce_new_customer_data', array(
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_pass' => $password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'twitter_username' => $twitter_username,
        'role' => 'customer',
        'user_url' => 'this is url'
    ));

    $customer_id = wp_insert_user($new_customer_data);
```

Comment: does $twitter_username has value? did you check that ?

Comment: @ IseNgaRt yes i have checked it has value.

Comment: You added a new column in wp_users table ?

Comment: @ Ashish yes i have added new column in wp-users

Comment: @usmankhalid It is not a good approach to alter tables shipped with Wordpress. You can achieve your target without that, too. You can insert additional fields in User meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you

```
$new_customer_data  = array(
     'user_login' => $username,
    'user_pass' => $password,
    'user_email' => $email,
    'role' => 'customer',
);

//Using WP inbuilt function to create users
$user = wp_insert_user($new_customer_data);

//Adding additional data in user meta
add_user_meta($user, 'twitter_username', $twitter_username);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can store this twitter_username in usermeta try this code.
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'twitter_username', $twitter_username);

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_customer_data = apply_filters_ref_array('woocommerce_new_customer_data', array(
'user_login' => $username,
'user_pass' => $password,
'user_email' => $email,
'twitter_username' => $twitter_username,
'role' => 'customer',
'user_url' => 'this is url'
));

$customer_id = wp_insert_user($new_customer_data);

//On success
if ( ! is_wp_error($customer_id ) ) {
echo "User created : ".  $customer_id;
}
```